CGAL How to iterate through the boundary of each face within an arrangment
I have a spherical arrangement created from a spherical triangle. The curve splits the sphere into two faces. One that is the spherical triangle, and the other is the complement face. Hence, I am trying to get this expected output
Face 0: // the spherical triangle face
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0

Face 1: // the complement face
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0

#include <list>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_on_surface_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2.h>
#include "arr_print.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel         Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Arr_geodesic_arc_on_sphere_traits_2<Kernel>         Geom_traits;
typedef Geom_traits::Point_2                                      Point;
typedef Geom_traits::Curve_2                                      Curve;
typedef CGAL::Arr_spherical_topology_traits_2<Geom_traits>        Topol_traits;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_on_surface_2<Geom_traits, Topol_traits> Arrangement;


int main()
{
    Geom_traits traits;
    Arrangement arr(&traits);
    auto ctr_p = traits.construct_point_2_object();
    auto ctr_cv = traits.construct_curve_2_object();

    std::list<Curve> arcs;
    arcs.push_back(ctr_cv(ctr_p(1, 0, 0), ctr_p(0, 1, 0)));
    arcs.push_back(ctr_cv(ctr_p(0, 1, 0), ctr_p(0, 0, 1)));
    arcs.push_back(ctr_cv(ctr_p(0, 0, 1), ctr_p(1, 0, 0)));

    CGAL::insert(arr, arcs.begin(), arcs.end());

    typename Arrangement::Face_const_iterator fit;
    for(fit = arr.faces_begin(); fit != arr.faces_end(); ++fit)
    {
        if (fit->is_unbounded()) continue; 
        
        // How to print the XYZ position of each vertex
        // from each face.

    }
    

   return 0;
}


However, I struggle using the const counter clockwise boundary (ccb) iterators.
I've tried something like this:
    Arrangement::Inner_ccb_const_iterator hc_it;
    for (hc_it = fit->inner_ccbs_begin(); hc_it != fit->inner_ccbs_end(); ++hc_it) {
        Arrangement::Halfedge_handle he_handle = hc_it; // error here (can't convert)
        // how can I get the vertex data?
    }


The unbounded face is the face that maps to the entire sphere.

The unbounded face maps to the entire sphere. It is one of the two faces of the arrangement. This face has one inner CCB, which is incident to the other face. This other face has one outer CCB. So, don't skip it in the loop.
